# Integral Dependence of Symmetric functions (from Mumford's Red Book of Schemes)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, $S= k[X_1,..., X_n]$ be the ring of polynomials,
$L= Frac(S)$ the fraction field on $S$ and $f(T)=
T^m +a_{m-1} T^{m-1}+ ...+ a_0 \in L[T]$ an *irreducible*
polynomial. Since $char(k)=0$ this polynomial is separable and
therefore has exactly $m$ different zeroes $z_1,..., z_m \in \overline{L}$
in algebraic closure $\overline{L}$ of $L$.

Let $N_L := L(z_1,..., z_m) \subset \overline{L}$ the splitting field
of $f(T)$ which by definition is generated by it's zeroes $z_k$.
So $L \subset N$ is a finite normal extension, therefore Galois. Therefore in
$N[T]$ the polynomial $f$ splits in linear factors as
$f(T)= \prod^m_{i=1} (T-z_i)$.

Then obviously all the coefficients $a_i$ of $f$ are *symmetric polynomials*
in $z_1,..., z_m$.

Question: Why this implies that all $a_i$ are *integral dependent* over $S$?
That is why for every $a_j$ there exist a normed polynomial
$P_j(T)= T^{m_j}+ c_{j, (m_j-1)} T^{m_j-1}+ ...+c_{j, 0} \in S[T]$
with $P_j(a_j)=0$ with *integral(!)* coefficents.

About motivation: This argument David Mumford uses in his Red Book of
Schemes on page 43 to prove Algebraic Version of Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem.
Mumford also noted that this proof is due to John Tate. But I nowhere found
a version of it, which might explain this step in more detail. Nevertheless here
the proof

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true in general, just simply take $f(T)=T- \dfrac{1}{X_1}$ then $\dfrac{1}{X_1}$ is not integral dependent over $S$.

The result in Mumford's book, however, is correct. The essential assumption here is that, with notation in the book, $f$ is also integrally dependent over $S$, i.e, it satisfies another equation: $$Y^k + b_1Y^{k-1} + \ldots + b_k =0$$
where $b_i$ are in $S$. Therefore, all of its conjugates (zeros of the minimal polynomial $Y^n + a_1Y^{n-1} + \ldots + a_n$) are also roots of the above equation, thus, are also integrally dependent over $S$. It follows that since each $a_i$ is a symmetric polynomial on those conjugates, $a_i$ must be integrally dependent over $S$ as well.